# How can I get top command output in real time in Mac Os

Tags: node.js, child-process

I want to monitor server and show top command output in real time on webpage.
there is an error `error: initializing curses` after program started on *Mac OS*.
I don't know how to deal with it, my question is how to get top command output in real time via Node.JS?

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    com = spawn('/usr/bin/top', []); 
var io = require('socket.io').listen(5555);
  com.stdout.on('data', function(data){
    io.sockets.emit('get result', data);
  }
  );
com.stderr.on('data', function(data){
console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

If you run `top` in a command window, it updates the data on the screen, using the curses library. Try using the batch-mode '-b' option on top to see if that'll allow node to pipe its output into your

Comment: Thank you. i'm not found the '-b' option in terminal shell in Mac OS (V10.6.8)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like OSX's `top` command has to be called with `-l` flag (other UNIXes use `-b`).
With that flag "curses" library is no longer required (this lib does fancy formatting for default interactive mode) so piping begins to work.

Here is the code to start with:

```
var top = spawn("top", ["-l 0"]);
top.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
top.stderr.on("data", function(data) {
  console.log("ps stderr: " + data);
});
```